# Input first number: =thread-exited,id="2",group-id="i1"

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading

This is my `Unary operator.cpp` file

```
#include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    class space{
        int x;
        int y;
        int z;
        public: 
        void getdata(int a, int b, int c){
            x=a;
            y=b;
            z=c;
        }
        void display(){
            cout<<x<<" ";
            cout<<y<<" ";
            cout<<z<<"\n";
        }
        void operator-(){
            x=-x;
            y=-y;
            z=-z;
        }
    };
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        space S;
        S.getdata(10,-20,30);
        cout<<"S: ";
        S.display();
        -S;
        S.display();
        return 0;
    }
```

This is my code for Overloading Unary Operator. When I compile this code in VS Code this appears in debug console `Input first number: =thread-exited,id="2",group-id="i1"`  sometimes. And sometime code compiles successfully by showing this message  `The program 'e:\C++\Unary operator.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x00000000)` 
.  But when I run it in Code Blocks It compiles and output appears as expected. I think there is something wrong with VS code. Please help.

Comment: What do you expect to see in the debug console? Are you looking for the terminal the program is running in instead?

Comment: Exit code `0`, means that it finished successfully. Do you think, that it shouldn't?

Comment: code looks fine. `operator-` should return something, but thats just a matter of convention. "Input first number:" looks like it is from different code.

Comment: not the problem in your current code, but you should write a constructor that initializes the members

Comment: You might need to flush `cout`.

Comment: @AlanBirtles
There is no output in the terminal.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius
I am new to C++, so I don't have that much idea about it. 
I expects some output in terminal

Comment: you are confusing some things here. If you see something in the debugger console it means the code was already compiled successfully. Especially "has exited with code 0 " means that it was compiled and executed without problems.

Comment: @MikeVine
Can you help with complete code?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number
But output of this code is not shown in terminal.

Comment: @RoshanOjha "_I am new to C++, so I don't have that much idea about it_" Applications finishing with return code `0` meaning success doesn't have anything to do with C++.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius
But in VS code Output is not shown in terminal like Code Blocks.